# Why does using a custom GuidConverter that returns null cause a strange exception in viewstate serialization?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `UserControl` that uses a `Guid` stored in `ViewState` which is occasionally `Guid.Empty`. I also have this `GuidConverter` registered in my system:

```
public class GuidConverter : System.ComponentModel.GuidConverter {
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) {
        return typeof(IEnumerable<byte>).IsAssignableFrom(sourceType) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) {
        return destinationType == typeof(byte[]) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value) {
        if (value is IEnumerable<byte>) {
            return new Guid(((IEnumerable<byte>)value).ToArray());
        }
        if (value is string) {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value)) {
                return Guid.Empty;
            }
            return new Guid((string)value);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType) {
        if (destinationType == typeof(byte[])) {
            return ((Guid)value).ToByteArray();
        }
        if(destinationType == typeof(string)) {
            var g = (Guid)value;
            if (g == Guid.Empty) {
                return null; //here is the cause of the problem
            }

            return g.ToString("N");
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

When that `ViewState` `Guid` is `Guid.Empty` I get this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Error serializing value '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' of type 'System.Guid.' ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.SerializeValue(SerializerBinaryWriter writer, Object value)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.SerializeValue(SerializerBinaryWriter writer, Object value)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Stream outputStream, Object stateGraph)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Object stateGraph)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Serialize(Object state)
   at System.Web.UI.Util.SerializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, Object stateGraph)
   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Save()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(Object state)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I can get rid of the error by replacing `null` with `string.Empty` in the commented line above, but it is possible that the code using that converter may differentiate between the two cases in a way incompatible with that change (for example I may store the string form in a database and another application may read that value and do different things depending on whether the field is null or not).

Why does this happen?

---

In other words: If I ultimately provide an implementation of [`TypeConverter.ConvertToInvariantString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xc1782a.aspx), does it imply anywhere that I cannot return null? Did I find a bug in System.Web.dll or something missing in the documentation for this method?